# Wallets begining with 0x

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, address, cardano-address

I've seen multiple blockchains (eth, bnb, avalanche) that support wallets that begin with `0x`, that way we have 1 wallet for multiple chains, is this possible with cardano or we are fixed to addresses begining in `addr....` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Catalyst proposal](https://cardano.ideascale.com/a/dtd/Wallet-Name-System-WNS/333080-48088) is trying to achieve a DNS for Wallets (WNS) on Cardano. Theoretically you can assign different wallets to one address.
Also, [Unstoppable Domains](https://unstoppabledomains.com/apps) might support Cardano soon.

Comment: that would be great, because having 1 wallet for each blockchain is just not great. Imagine having a different "real wallet" for each dollar bill you have, ex: 1 wallet for $1, one wallet for bills of $5, etc... I hope this gets implemented

Comment: I want to follow up and say that ADA handle will start with Beta sale on Nov 6th.

Comment: I’m familia, I’ve been following then. What I don’t know is if that will allow the hex address from metamask to be transformed